# Translation between the functor-of-point and locally ringed space approach to schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, functors

Functorially, we have the following defintions:

1. An affine scheme $U$ is a representable (covariant) functor $\mathsf{CRing} \to \mathsf{Sets}$.
2. A scheme $X$ can be defined as a locally representable cosheaf of sets on $\mathsf{CRing}$.

How then, can I recover the "traditional" definition that $U = (\text{Spec} A, \mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec} A})$ and $X = (|X|, \mathcal{O}_X)$ so I could look at the rings of functions above $U$ and $X$, preferably functorially ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Jantzen’s book Representations of Algebraic Groups does a good job of discussing this. For example, he introduces open and closed subfunctors, from which one can recover the topological space associated to a functor.

Comment: This is not quite right: a (functorial) scheme is _locally_ representable. in other words, it is a sheaf which is covered by affine schemes in a suitable way.

Comment: @JonathanSterling Whoops must've been a typo (I posted from my phone). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: no worries! i’m putting this as a comment because i don’t feel authoritative enough to write an answer, but my understanding is that the functorial perspective on general schemes arises as soon as you agree that affine schemes are formal duals of commutative rings. here is why: first, you consider the category of sheaves on the category of all schemes. in this case, it is obvious that a legitimate scheme will be a representable sheaf, period.

Comment: but then, to grasp schemes, it is enough to probe them by affines: so you may reconstruct this sheaf category by considering the smaller site of affine schemes, which is CRingOp. Of course, now the condition on a sheaf to be a scheme becomes more complicated, but this is the essence of the functorial geometry as far as i have understood it.